# Purée, punaise, putain !

Tags: expressions, jurons, origine-ou-raison

Les exclamations « *purée* » ou « *punaise* » sont souvent (mais pas toujours je pense) utilisables à la place de l'exclamation « *putain* » mais sont moins grossières. Le fait qu'elles commencent par la même syllabe me fait supposer que ces expressions ont peut-être été inventées après coup, pour éviter de jurer.

Connaissez-vous leur origine ?

D'ailleurs, quand est-ce que « putain » a commencé à être utilisé en tant que juron et comment en est-on arrivés à une utilisation aussi large ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1- Tout d'abord il faut nuancer la « grossièreté » de *putain*. D'où je viens (je suis méridional) ce n'est pas grossier et d'emploi relativement courant. Par exemple, un enseignant qui entend le mot dans une cour de récréation à Toulouse ou à Marseille n'interviendra pas, je doute qu'il en soit de même à Lille ou à Paris, où le petit écolier se fera réprimander !
Le mot *putain* vient du latin *putidus* : « pourri, qui pue, fétide ». *Put*, *pute*, au sens propre « puant », a pris dès le 11<sup>e</sup> siècle le sens figuré de « sale, mauvais, vil, méchant » s'appliquant spécialement à une femme lascive, débauchée.
La langue populaire en a fait une interjection pour marquer l'admiration, l'étonnement (1931). (*Dictionnaire Historique de la Langue Française*)

2- *Purée* comme interjection existe indépendamment de *putain*. Un des sens figuré de *purée*  est *pénurie d'argent*  *panade* et, par « métonymie, *purée* s'applique aussi à une personne dans l'embarras et est employé pour qualifier ce qui est signe de gêne ou de misère. Il est employé familièrement en interjection depuis 1895. » (*Dictionnaire Historique de la Langue Française*)
À noter que le mot *purée* au sens propre et le mot *purin* ont une même origine (*purer* -> purifer). La purée (au sens propre) au départ était ce qui a été criblé, purifié. Le purin est ce qu'il reste de non comestible.

En Français d'Algérie d'Afrique du nord le mot  *purée* (« *purée d'ta mère !* » ) a une valeur voisine de *putain* et son emploi en France avec ce sens s'est répandu dans les années 60 avec le retour des Français d'Algérie en France.

3- L'emploi interjectif de *punaise* est attesté pour la première fois en 1947 et est d'origine typiquement provençale. Le mot *punaise* vient d'un mot latin qui veut dire « *qui pue* » .

En conclusion le fil conducteur de ces trois mots semble être les mauvaises odeurs.

---

*Putain* has long lost its strength as a swearword. In the south of France it is widely used and not considered rude. As an example I'd say a teacher hearing the kids say it in the playground in the south of France won't take notice, it might be different in Lille or Paris.
*Putain* comes from the Latin *putidus* that means "rotten, stinking". In the 11th century, *put, pute*, meaning "stinking" in Old French took the meaning of "dirty, vile" and was applied to debauched women. Around the middle of the 20th century the word had evolved to become an interjection depicting wonder or admiration. (source [Dictionnaire historique de la langue française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_historique_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise))

2- *Purée* has been used as a interjection since the middle of the 19th century. It is to be noted that it has the same etymology as *purin* (English "manure"), (from *purer*→ to purify). In the literal sense the *purée* is the edible part left after purification and *purin* the non edible part.

In Algerian French *purée* (as in *purée d'ta mère*) is very close to *putain*, it stated being used in France around the 1960s under the influence of the repatriates from Algeria.

3- *Punaise* originates in Provence and appeared as an interjection in the middle of the 20th century. It comes from  *puteo* (puer).

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que ces expressions ont été « inventées » pour éviter de dire un gros mot à voix haute. On prononce le début du mot, puis on change la fin du mot au dernier moment. Il y a également *mercredi* pour remplacer *merde*.

Je ne pense pas qu'il faille y chercher de liens étymologiques entre le différents mots. C'est probablement purement phonétique.

C'est une sorte d'euphémisme. Les anglophones ont d'ailleurs une expression pour désigner ce type de substitution : [Minced Oath <sup>wiki</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath)

Answer (score 1):

"punaise" est un terme populaire pour désigner une femme méchante (cf. Larousse en ligne)
J'ai un ami périgourdin qui ponctue toutes ses phrases de "putain-con!". Prononcé avec l'accent méridional, cela n'a rien de vulgaire. C'est plus amusant qu'un tic de langage comme "voyez" ou "bon" ou "euh", ou "ouais" à la place de "oui".
Les usages évoluent et il faut tenir compte du contexte et du ton employé.

Comment: Bienvenue sur StackExchange, vous pouvez faire un lien vers une ressource en ligne dans vos réponses avec le format [texte](lien) par exemple pour [punaise sur Larousse en ligne](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/punaise/65084)