# Putain - grossier ou pas?

Tags: traduction, interjections, exclamations, grossieretes

J'étudie le français à l'université comme langue étrangère et en ce moment, j'effectue un travail sur l'expression "putain" dans sa traduction dans langue maternelle. Comme je ne connais pas trop de français, qui peut m'aider avec ça ? je suis venu pour vous interroger à ce sujet.

Donc ma question : comment percevrez-vous cette exclamation ? Est-elle grossière pour vous ou pas ? Et d'où venez-vous?

J'ai lu plusieurs articles concernant ce thème et donc ma prémisse est que ça dépend de la région - elle est beaucoup plus « acceptée » dans le sud que dans le nord. Mon but est pourtant de rassembler le plus de réponses possible pour que mon travail soit pertinent.

---

Je voudrais encore préciser que je suis bien consciente du fait que ce mot s'utilise pour désigner une prostituée, je connais même son étymologie, tout ça. Ce qui m'intéresse, c'est surtout son utilisation comme interjection/exclamation (de colère, d'étonnement etc...) dans la vie quotidienne. Il se peut que j'aie mal posé ma question.

Ici quelques liens pour mieux comprendre: [Purée, punaise, putain !](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/pur%C3%A9e-punaise-putain)
https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/putain-merde.2590996/

Quand vous avez mentionné les registres, j'ai trouvé (larousse, le grand robert etc.) que cette expression, quand utilisée comme interjection, appartient plutôt dans le registre populaire. Est-que c'est une différence importante ou seulement un detail, une formalité?

Comment: As with English f---, this word holds the odd distinction of being both universally recognized as in the set of strongest "swear words", and thus likely to offend some people, yet also used casually and lightly by some people (usually young) without much eyebrow-raising. Heck, even 60 years ago Brassens sang "Putain de toi" and considering how vulgarity tends to lose its force, you can guess how likely it is to sound less awful nowadays. Not that you would say it around kids or your grandma. Just my two cents.

Comment: Putain pour une étudiante en Français tu écris bien !

Comment: La différence nord/sud est sensible mais le registre et le contexte sont bien plus importants pour évaluer le degré de grossièreté de *putain*.  Dans tous les stades de de football et les cours de récréations de France , *putain* émaillera beaucoup de conversations alors qu'à l'inverse, on risquera peu de l'entendre dans les églises, les musées, les restaurants ou les bibliothèques...

Comment: @jlliagre: Que signifie le tag « ans »?

Comment: @toto rien, sûrement le résultat d'une fausse manip. Je l'ai supprimé.

Answer (score 5):

Bonjour, "putain" est une expression très grossière dans toute la France, c'est l’équivalent du "fuck" en anglais. **Putain** est un mot qui a l'origine désigne les prostituées qui sont familièrement appelées les putains. Le sens du mot a ensuite quelque peu évolué et aujourd'hui c'est une expression très utilisée dans le registre familier (a ne surtout pas dire en présence de personnes a respecter) pour exprimer tout un tas de chose: la frustration, le bonheur, la joie, la colère. Putain peut se dire dans quasiment toutes les circonstances. A ma connaissance c'est le mot vulgaire le plus utilisé en France avec "merde".

Answer (score 5):

C'est à la base un mot grossier utilisé pour désigner de manière vulgaire une prostituée ("c'est une putain").
Il est surtout utilisé aujourd'hui comme interjection en cas de forte frustration (quand quelque chose ne marche pas comme on veut pas exemple), au même titre que "merde !", etc.
C'est un gros mot malgré tout, et il n'est pas conseillé de l'utiliser en public. Cependant, il est beaucoup utilisé dans des milieux plus familiers (on l'utilise beaucoup à mon travail, entre nous), ou chez les jeunes.
En public, il est plutôt préférable d'utiliser d'autres interjections comme "Zut", "Punaise", etc...

Comment: J'entends « mince » beaucoup aussi

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

Cette expression est extrêmement grossière. Elle est acceptée chez la plupart des gens mais reste vulgaire tout de même. Quant à son acceptation, tout dépend du contexte et de qui l'entend.

- Lorsqu'on est entre amis, cette expression peut paraître banale. `Putain mec, tu gères !`
- Lorsque ce mot est utilisé comme une insulte, cela devient extrêmement grossier, peu importe le destinataire de ce mot. `Sale putain de boulanger !`
- Lorsque ce mot est utilisé comme interjection, tout dépend de qui l'entend. Certaines personnes l'accepteront et ne s'en soucieront pas tandis que d'autre seront affectés par cela. `Putain, où est-ce que j'ai foutu mes clés !`.

Quant à moi, je le perçois de manière vulgaire mais l'accepte malgré tout selon le contexte. Comme le mot "fuck" en anglais (`fuck you moron!`, `I fucking love you!`). Quant à ma région, je vis en Belgique, à Bruxelles.

Answer (score 0):

C'est une expression vraiment grossière, à éviter en public, si possible. Un jour j'ai dit “P… de B… de M… !” devant une personne qui m'était chère, et elle a cru que je la traitais de prostituée. Ce n'était pas du tout le cas (je venais de casser ma clé dans la serrure, et on se retrouvait coincés dehors, tous les deux, à minuit passé, loin de tout serrurier), et je crois même avoir lu cette expression dans un roman de Daniel Pennac (que j'aime beaucoup malgré tout), mais c'est à éviter absolument.

Ou alors, quand on est ABSOLUMENT CERTAIN qu'on est tout seul. Mais JAMAIS en public !