# « Putain », « merde » et « bordel » : sont-ils grossiers ?

Tags: oral, vulgarité, grossieretes

I know obviously their meaning, (a little bit of) their etymology and the like as well as, more or less, their usage in colloquial speech.

I have heard that some teachers (professeurs du secondaire) use these words **in the class during the courses in front of their students** (e.g. when the students are very noisy or when either a student or the prof has made a "stupid" mistake).

Is this behavior considered a normal and acceptable one? Are these words considered rude ones or not? Does the answer depend on the region (north, south of France, etc.)? A student could use them in the class in front of the teacher?

In addition, is it considered acceptable if a boss use these words (or similar wording) when he or she speaks to his or her employees?

PS.
I have seen the question here: [Putain - grossier ou pas?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30722/putain-grossier-ou-pas)

---

Je connais évidemment leur sens, (un peu de) leur étymologie, etc., et plus ou moins leur utilisation dans le langage courant.

J'ai entendu dire que certains professeurs (du secondaire) utilisent ces mots **dans la classe pendant les cours et auprès de leurs étudiants** (par exemple, lorsque les étudiants sont très bruyants ou lorsqu'un élève ou le prof a fait une  erreur « stupide »).

Ce comportement est-il considéré comme normal et acceptable ? Ces mots sont-ils considérés comme grossiers ou non? La réponse dépend-elle de la région (nord, sud de France, etc.) ? Un étudiant pourrait-il les utiliser dans la classe devant l'enseignant ?

En outre, est-il considéré comme acceptable qu'un patron utilise ces mots (ou des mots similaires) lorsqu'il parle à ses employés?

PS
J'ai vu la question ici: [Putain - grossier ou pas?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30722/putain-grossier-ou-pas)

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/pur%c3%a9e-punaise-putain

Possible double.  Mince.

Comment: @livresque Merci pour la question "linké".

Comment: The use of the word "Hexagon" to mean "France" was once the subject of one of your questions and you accepted, I believe, the conclusion from the Ac.  : Spécialement. Fam. L’Hexagone, la France, par vague assimilation du tracé de ses frontières à une figure hexagonale. ◉ Cet emploi est à déconseiller.

Comment: @LPH I edited the question and replaced the Hexagon reference.

Comment: *Bordel* is probably used less than the other two. I even wonder if it is not getting outdated. The thing is that the use of *putain* and *bordel*, because of their sexual connotations, are felt like insults to women and some people avoid using them on that ground. Although, as [I've already said](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2177/358) *putain* has long lost its strength as a swearword in the south of France.

Comment: Tu n'envisages pas [*bordel de merde*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bordel_de_merde) dans ta liste ? L'usage en classe des trois que tu cites n'a rien de surprenant (même si ce n'est pas courant) par contre celui-ci est plus rarement envisageable.

Comment: @Laure Donc non surprenant un tel vocabulaire. J'ai appris quelque chose.☺

Comment: Toute réponse à la question que tu poses ne peut qu'être **subjective**. Aucune réponse scientifique ne ne peut être faite.  Ce n'est pas une question de langue mais d'**expérience personnelle**. Chacun te donnera son avis qui est vu par le prisme de sa propre histoire, sa sensibilité, son milieu social, le pays où il vit, etc., ce sont des jugements personnels et non neutres.  La réponse de OKman65 est à mon avis la seule raisonnable qui puisse être faite, comme il le dit, c'est un « conseil ».

Comment: @Laure Merci pour les commentaires. Je te felicite aussi pour ta réponse ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/pur%c3%a9e-punaise-putain/2177#2177 Je n'ai pas inclus  bordel de merde parce que je ne l'ai pas connu:-)! Je connais quelques mots et expressions grossiers/vulgaires. Quand j'ai appris que il existe des profs qui utilisent putain, merde et bordel dans la classe j'étais suppris, voire choqué. Je pratique le français dans un cadre professionnel (université) deouis plusieurs années mais mon environnement n'utilise un tel vocabulaire. D'où la manque de familiarité.

Comment: Je pense que ça peut être utilisé par des professeurs uniquement dans l'enseignement supérieur, où on considère que les étudiants sont plus ou moins adultes, et les professeurs ne sont plus là pour faire leur éducation.

Comment: @Laure Bordel de merde est un vrai juron, et je ne vois pas de situation où un professeurs pourrait utiliser ça. Par contre, juste "bordel" me paraît très envisageable : "*Comme vous voyez, dès qu'on a 3 variables ou plus ça devient un peu le bordel*"

Comment: @TeleportingGoat C'est bien pour ça que j'ai écrit « par contre celui-ci est plus rarement envisageable. » !!!

Comment: Afterthought... Je fais une différence entre  « bordel ! » (juron) et dire « c'est le bordel »(nom = désordre).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of them (*putain*, *bordel*, *merde*) are clearly **rude words**, and are far from being considered acceptable in *all* situations, or as words from a standard register. For instance, none of these would be acceptable in a job interview. A secondary school teacher teaching in the presence of another adult (another teacher, inspector, parent...) would certainly avoid using any of them. Nobody would use them in writing in a normal professional context.

However, they are all **extremely common** in colloquial French, in conversations with friends,  in self-directed speech (« Merde, j'ai laissé tombé mes papiers »), and are frequently used in informal conversations with colleagues for instance.

The question of their **acceptability** highly depends on the social context: who is talking to whom (social origins, age, socio-economic status, power relationship...), where and for what.

In a **professional context**, outside of informal “coffee-machine” talk, their use is clearly possible, but would probably occur in an angry or highly emotional reaction. I could typically imagine Emmanuel Macron use any of the three in a harsh internal discussion with his ministers (actually, [Macron has used *bordel* in a public conversation with another politician](https://www.europe1.fr/politique/bordel-ce-qua-dit-emmanuel-macron-3455585), but in its substantive form — « foutre le bordel » —, and it caused a small scandal; another example: [Sarkozy used *merde* in a private phone call to the president of his party](https://www.lexpress.fr/actualite/politique/lr/grosse-merde-la-reponse-musclee-de-sarkozy-a-wauquiez_1986640.html)). In school too, I remember one or two teachers flying off the handle and using *merde* and *bordel* (not *putain*, but that was a long time ago; it could certainly happen today, depending on the formality of the school).

In general, I think *merde* can be considered milder than *bordel*, itself maybe slightly milder than *putain*: ***merde* < *bordel* ≤ *putain***. If you are familiar with their equivalent in English, I believe *merde* is used with approximately the same level of informality as *shit*, and *putain* corresponds very closely to the uses of *fuck*.

Regarding **regional differences**, in France, they are more frequent and considered milder in the South of France than in the North. Generally, the North (Lille, Nancy...), as well as Belgium (and probably other peripheral regions such as Switzerland), tends to be more conservative and these words are there less acceptable than in Southern France, where they might be ubiquitous.

---

(EDIT: I corrected the last paragraph regarding regional differences. Previous version was: “I am not aware of strong regional differences on the matter. It is probably less frequent in Belgium (as possibly in Switzerland) than in France, and more common in the South of France than in the North, but I am not even sure the difference is significant.”)

Comment: Je trouve très efficace « n'importe quoi ! » pour remplacer les gros mos à cause de l'expression : "tu n'as pas le droit de faire n'importe quoi" à l'école.  Cela m'empêche de dire "arrête les conneries !"

Comment: My feeling has always been that they are less profane than "fuck" but more than "damn" somewhere around or just below "shit".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. "*... In school too, I remember one or two teachers flying off the handle and using merde and bordel (not putain, but that was a long time ago; it could certainly happen today, depending on the formality of the school).*" So, is it acceptable in France such wording by a teacher inside his or her class? What do you mean by "formality of school"?

Comment: There definitely are regional differences. Generally, the further north you go, the ruder words become. “Putain cong” in Toulouse or Marseille is about equivalent to “zut” in Lille, where “putain” can get you dirty looks.

Comment: The difference in the use of *putain* between the north and the south of France is [still](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2177/358) **significant**.   "A secondary school teacher teaching in the presence of another adult (another teacher, inspector, parent...) would certainly avoid using any of them.": well, you'd be surprised ! and there's nothing new about it.

Comment: @Dimitris: Totally acceptable, no. But it does happen (in tense moments, in some cases unintentionally). In my case, it was in Belgium, in a relatively more traditional school (which is what I mean by "formal"): after it, the word was running that teacher X had said "merde" or "bordel" in a fit of anger, and the teacher was not happy about it, or was denying it. There may be less traditional schools today where it happens frequently, maybe systematically. But it is certainly not acceptable everywhere.

Comment: @Laure and Gilles: you are both right. I underestimated the difference. I corrected the paragraph :-)

Answer (score 3):

Extending just a little on iNyar's comment about regional differences, "putain" and "bordel" are uncommon in Quebec ([we have a distinct set of profanities from European French speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_profanity)), and when used are milder than most Quebec profanities. "Merde" is more common, though usually in the regional form "marde" (e.g. *ostie de marde*, *mange de la marde*, *maudite marde* etc.), especially in compounds. As a lone word, it's also pretty mild.

Comment: Thanks for the complementary answer. Do (French) Canadian teachers use such profanities in their class?

Answer (score -2):

La grossièreté n'est qu'un jugement relatif à un ensemble de critères; il y a les personnes qui ont une idée de certains critères et qui adhèrent à ceux-ci et pour eux la grossièreté est réelle; ils y a celles qui ne sont pas conscientes de critères bien définis et qui identifient des effets de la grossièreté reconnue par d'autres, ces effets étant considérés comme  négatifs, et pour eux elle est à éviter; il y a enfin celles qui ne sont réellement conscientes ni de critères ni d'effets ou s'en soucient peu, du fait de leur éducation  ou par nature ou les deux, et pour qui l'idée de grossièreté effleure à peine l'esprit; la grossièreté n'est pas réelle pour ces dernières. On réduit ainsi approximativement l'appréhension de la grossièreté à trois modèles. Ces mots sont donc grossiers ou non, selon une certaine modalité, selon qui vous vous trouvez être.

On peut dire que ces trois catégories de personnes ont constitué des groupes dont le nombre de chacun et donc l'influence continuent à changer et que demander à n'importe qui dans un de ces groupes s'il y a une implication de grossièreté c'est considérer leur approche personnelle à la grossièreté.

On peut dire aussi que ceux pour qui la grossièreté est réelle ont cette réaction de rejet des mots considérés, d'une part en vertu de la notion d'une  familiarité avec les choses nommées implicitement et/ou d'une haine particulière de celles-ci qui se dégagerait de l'utilisation courante de ces mots comme étant la leur, non pas qu'ils prétendent n'avoir aucune connaissance de ces choses mais qu'ils les rejettent elles-mêmes. D'autre part la grossièreté est identifiée, toujours sur la base d'un critère fondamental, dans l'arbitraire des références implicites ; pourquoi ces mots plutôt que d'autres ? Cette part de la  grossièreté est beaucoup moins importante ; prouvent cela l'utilisation des euphémismes employés à leur place (Oui ! « zut » est encore grossier …).

Ces mots seront donc grossiers ou non pour vous aussi selon que vous adhèrerez ou non à ces critères et possiblement d'autres tels critères de rejet ou selon que vous aurez foi en l'adhérence d'une section suffisamment influente de la population à la conviction qu'ils sont grossiers, mais alors dans ce dernier cas vous ne saurez dire pourquoi.

Je pense donc que l'on ne peut pas donner de réponse vu que, plus particulièrement de nos jours il n'existe pas une référence de ce qu'est la grossièreté; ce patron hypothétique grossier dont vous parlez ne paraitra grossier que pour ceux qui jugent son vocabulaire grossier et ils peuvent ne pas être très nombreux en comparaison de ce ceux qui peuvent juger, au contraire, que son vocabulaire est la marque (par exemple) du patron pugnace ; cet état de chose tel que je crois le comprendre est tout à fait analogue à ce que résume l'adage « Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. » ? ([ref.](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beauty-is-in-the-eye-of-the-beholder.html)).

Il est évident que ces mots ont été considérés comme étant  grossiers, mais dire qu'ils sont grossiers dans les contextes actuels qui résultent d'une évolution que l'on réexamine maintenant et où ces mots ont gagné en tolérance, c'est impossible: ils sont grossiers pour certain et pas pour d'autres. Il n'y a pas deux contextes où ces mots seront  grossiers dans l'un et pas dans l'autre, si l'on s'en tient à un sens absolu du mot « grossier » ; il n'existe pas de sens absolu. Ils ne devraient pas être considérés comme grossiers dans un groupe donné vu que la majorité est peu soucieuse de principes et les utilise couramment mais ils le seraient dans les bouches de ce même groupe lorsque  il est considéré par un autre groupe social ne  partageant pas leur façon de voir ? Cela n'a aucun sens.

La question « Est-ce qu'un élève est justifié dans son utilisation de ces mots à partir du moment où il les  entend dans la bouche de ses professeurs ? » ne se pose pas. L'élève (jeune) est plus ou moins la victime tant que le professeur est jugé avoir un comportement inacceptable ; en exagérant beaucoup, doit-on se demander si l'élève est justifié dans la recherche de plaisir anormaux auxquels il a été introduit par son professeur qui est donné à la pédérastie ? Bien sûr que non.

Comment: La question du jour:-)! Pourquoi les notes négatives ? (3 !) (Question rhétorique...)

Comment: @Dimitris Je ne peux pas savoir ; il y a un grand nombre d'idées dans cette réponse et ce qui a déclenché le sentiment d'adversité chez ceux qui ont donné ces votes pourrait être n'importe quoi. Peut être que c'est l'idée de l'inexistence de la grossièreté absolue que je met en avant ou celle de l'inanité du concept que pour une même personne ils puissent être grossier dans un contexte donné mais pas dans un autre.